# python child Tk window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code where I have a drop down menu and what I need to do is that when I select an entry from the drop down list (ex: Send an email) and press on go, I need this to populate another tk window (child window).

I know I am doing something wrong but can not comprehend how to overcome this, I have been searching for a while but I am unable to find a solution or guidance on how to complete this.

Thanks in advance for your help with this!

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x100")
#========================================
#Entry area to enter the number

labelmain = Label(root,text="Please enter number:")
labelmain.pack()
entryvar = StringVar(root)
entrymain = Entry(root, textvariable=entryvar,width=30)
entrymain.pack()
#========================================
#Create option drop down list:
lst = ["Save details to DB", "Send an email", "Copy format", "email",     "View report"]
ddl = StringVar(root)
ddl.set(lst[0])
option = OptionMenu(root, ddl, *lst)
option.pack()
#========================================
#Function to get the values from drop down list
def ok():
    print("value is: " + ddl.get())
    #root.quit()
#=========================================
#Button to process the selection:

btnmain = Button(root,text="Go", command=ok)
btnmain.pack()
#=========================================

if ddl.get() == "Send an email":
    samepmrdb = Tk()
    samepmrdb.mainloop()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you need to be more specific. What is this code doing that is different from what you want?

Comment: Apologies Bryan, this was my first question in stackoverflow so will ensure in the future  to be more specific for my request, thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the value of `ddl` right after you open up your window.  As you said in your question, you want some stuff happen after pressing the button so you need to put those codes under the command of said button.

Also, a tkinter app should only have one `Tk()` instance and one `mainloop`. When you want to open another window, you should use `Toplevel()`.

```
def ok():
    print("value is: " + ddl.get())
    if ddl.get() == "Send an email":
        samepmrdb = Toplevel()
        #now you can populate samepmrdb as  you like
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this, this is exactly what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking to do is find a way to update a second `tkinter` window with the selection from an `OptionMenu` on the first `tkinter` window this can be achieved easily using the below code:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.top = Toplevel(master)
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.var = StringVar()
        self.var.set("Example1")
        self.option = OptionMenu(self.top, self.var, "Example1", "Example2", "Example3", "Example4")
        self.button = Button(self.top, text="Ok", command=lambda:self.command(self.var))
        self.label = Label(self.master)
        self.option.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.label.pack()
    def command(self, var):
        self.master.deiconify()
        self.label.configure(text=var.get())
        self.label.pack()

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This creates a `Toplevel` widget which contains an `OptionMenu` and `Button` widget. The `Button` widget will then output the selection from the `OptionMenu` widget when pressed.

This kind of logic can be used for all sorts of things and it's relatively simple to pass information from one window to another, provided this is what your question is asking.

Comment: You are correct on this, this do exactly what I need as well, so I will review and study this valuable code :) Thank you so much for your help on this!

Comment: If this answers your question can you please mark it as the accepted answer so that other users can learn from this too?